# R: understanding interaction term between two continuous vars when one is set to zero

Tags: r, glm, predict

I'm not quite sure if this is an implementation (coding) problem or a model interpretation one. But I'll put the question in SO and hope it doesn't need to be moved.

I'm fitting a logistic regression (toy example provided below), where for each observation, one of the explanatory variables (`time.since.last.action`) is a continuous value but for some observations, the action never occurred, in which this would typically be an NA (I've set it to zero but flagged it in the `last.action.flag` variable). I would like to retain `time.since.last.action` as a continuous variable, but for observations where there is no action, I would like the term including `time.since.last.action` to evaluate to zero. N.B: I've do not want to lose information by 'discretising' the time.since.last.action into categories so as to deal with the no action observations.

I had hoped to achieve this by using the numeric predictor (`last.action.flag`, 0 - no action, 1 - action), and interacting it with the `time.since.last.action` predictor.

```
df = data.frame(outcome = factor(c(rep("Success", 3), rep("Failure", 3)), levels = c("Failure", "Success")),  
                time.since.last.action = c(2.5,3.5,3.3, 0, 7, 0.25), last.action.flag = c(1,1,1,0,1,1), 
                last.action.factor = factor(c("Action","Action","Action","No.Action", "Action","Action"), levels=c("No.Action", "Action")))

glm1 = glm(outcome ~  time.since.last.action:last.action.flag + last.action.factor, data = df, family = binomial(logit))
```

Now, when I look at the predicted terms for an example where there was no action, I see a non-zero value for the interaction term, which I didn't expect.

```
> df[4,]
  outcome time.since.last.action last.action.flag last.action.factor
4 Failure                      0                0          No.Action
> my.pred = predict(glm1, newdata=df[4,], type="terms")
> my.pred
  last.action.factor time.since.last.action:last.action.flag
4          -16.12049                               0.3064035
attr(,"constant")
[1] -2.751981
```

So I am either thinking that interactions don't work the way I think, or predict(type="terms") isn't producing what I thought it did...

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: This seems more a statistical methods question than a coding question.

Comment: From what I've just read, it seems to be returning the terms after centering. So I'll modify the question to ask how to get the uncentered terms. Actually, might be better to ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the `predict(..., type="terms")` function returns the centered term values (explained a bit here: [predict.lm(...,type="terms") question](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help//2012-August/334418.html)). However the solution posted on the linked site does not work for variables that generate a number of betas (factors, poly(), etc.). So I'll ask how to do that as a new question.